# SQL CASE WHEN a is NULL

Tags: sql, null, case

I have 3 columns all contain email addresses

```
email
alt_email
main_email
```

I wanted to do case when email is null then alt_email
when alt_email is null then email and when both are null then main_email end as all_emails.

I am not getting the correct answer as the total count for all_emails is way 90% less than the total all customers.

TIA

Comment: Your message isn't clear, but the COALESCE function should help.  You basically list all columns in the order to check them, and the first non-null column value is returned

Comment: sorry. what I mean is when column email is null i want to fill the blank with alt_email, if alt_email is blank/null then i want to fill the blank with email and if both are null then i want to fill the blank with main email and put that into a separate column.

Comment: *how* did you arrive at your "incorrect answer"? Maybe we can spot the issue, if you post your query, plus sample input and output (expected and actual). Please also [tag your DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - sql syntax can be DBMS-specific

Comment: @Sparky, thanks for your response. I got the answer that I wanted after thinking about what you said. Cheers.
HansKesting, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sparky mentioned, this is a job for COALESCE:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(email, alt_email, main_email) AS all_email FROM ...
```

it gets the first non-null value from the columns mentioned, in that order.

See docs for [SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql), but the same syntax applies to other DBMS's as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN email IS NULL AND alt_email IS NULL THEN main_email
    WHEN email IS NULL AND alt_email IS NOT NULL THEN alt_email
    WHEN alt_email IS NULL AND email IS NOT NULL THEN email
    ELSE email
END AS all_emails
FROM some_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select CASE WHEN (email != '') THEN email WHEN (alt_email != '') THEN alt_email ELSE main_email END AS emaiId From table

Comment: watch out, an empty string is not the same as `null` in most DBMS's